# How to make a "back" link in Kentico CMS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kentico

I have a website which use Kentico CMS. On each website I have few webparts and in one of them I would like to add "go back" link. I try to do it in that way:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlkGoBack" Text="Go back" NavigateUrl="#" OnClick="javascript:history.go(-1)" Visible="true"></asp:HyperLink>
```

But it doesn't work - it redirect me to a CMSWebPart folder.

Do you have any working ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the pure HTML:

`<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlkGoBack" Text="Go back" NavigateUrl="javascript:history.go(-1)" Visible="true"></asp:HyperLink>
```